# jq filter for AWS for description without calling jq twice?

Tags: json

I have this to filter out snapshots with `Jenkins` in the description. Is there a more efficient way to do the same thing?

`aws --region eu-west-1 ec2 describe-snapshots | jq '.Snapshots[] |\ select(.Description | contains("Jenkins"))' | jq -r '.SnapshotId'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, You can use JMESPath Query inside your cli statement.

```
 aws --region eu-west-1 ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[?contains(Description, `Jenkins`) == `false`]'
```